# Troubleshooting Deadlock Issue After Updating to Windows 11 22H2

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

A couple weeks ago, when Windows 11 22H2 came out, I updated my machine to it. Since then, I have been encountering a very annoying issue where the machine will deadlock. I don't get any errors or blue screens. I will be using the machine, and one by one, the applications I have open will become unresponsive over the course of about 15 seconds, ultimately ending with the entire UI becoming unresponsive. The only way to work around the issue is to crash the machine and reboot it.

Under normal circumstances, my first thought would be that this is a hardware issue, probably with memory, but running memory tests hasn't surfaced any errors, and it also seems highly probable that the issue is a software one considering that this was not a problem before updating to 22H2. Since I believe it's a software issue, I have been trying to narrow down the source of the problem by digging through the Event Viewer logs, but I haven't seen anything noteworthy in there. At this point, I am at a loss for what would be the best way to troubleshoot this. Has anyone else seen this or have any ideas for how to troubleshoot it? I have also already tried the cliché recommendation of running `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and `sfc /scannow` to repair Windows component corruption as well, but that hasn't done anything of value. I didn't get any reports of corruption when running these commands.

Comment: NVIDIA or AMD GPU?

Comment: @Ramhound NVIDIA

Comment: There are several issues that are know with 22H2. The first thing that comes to mind is the GeForce Experience issues, that cause huge performance problems, and in my experience cause very similar problems on my own system until it was updated

Comment: You tested memory, now test all hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound When the 9/27/2022 NVIDIA update came out, I installed it immediately, but I have encountered this problem many times since then. Is there a BETA release that I should try, perhaps?

Comment: @John Aside from running memory tests, I'm not actually sure how I'd test the rest of the hardware.

Comment: Look in the Manufactuer's website for hardware tests.

Comment: How many tabs in your browser do you typically have open? I was running into performance issues with 700 tabs.  One of two issues solved a nearly identical issue I had, either closing a vast majority of those tabs, or updating the Nvidia drivers that were installed.  However, Windows 11 has some File Explorer issues, which is effecting SMB transfers.  Make sure you are running GeForce Experience 3.26

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion. I've found the testing utility for my manufacturer, so I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Ramhound lol I never get anywhere near 700 tabs. At most, I'll have about 30 open. Most of the time though, I don't even get close to that. I do use SMB though! Are the issues with SMB a potential source of the deadlock? As for GeForce Experience, I just checked. It is 3.26.0.131.

Comment: @DaveTheMinion - It's possible; Can you disconnect the SMB share to determine if that is indeed the case[?](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-confirms-performance-degradation-in-windows-11-22h2-when-copying-large-files/) It might not be related.

Comment: You could downgrade back to 21H2 and skip 22H2, or wait for it to stabilize. See [How to download Windows 11 21H2 ISO after 22H2 releases](https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-11-21h2-iso-after-22h2/).

Comment: It's only possible to rollback to 21H2 if it's before 7 days (I believe it's only 7 days), unless you extended the time, before the version was installed. By default it's an extremely short timeframe.

Comment: @Ramhound I can try it, but this issue occurs even when I am not copying anything to or from the SMB shares at all.

Comment: @harrymc I took a Clonezilla backup image of my drive before performing the update, so I can easily roll back. That said, I would really prefer to not need to do so. Also, the hardware test didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Having a similar issue here.  Also Nvidia (and hover between 200-300 Vivaldi tabs).  GeForce Experience 3.25.x, so I'll try to update -- I thought I already had updated right after the 22H2 issues were reported, but perhaps not.  It seems to be 10 days to rollback (Microsoft [doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5#bkmk_win11_go_back_previous_version)), and I'm at the 5 day mark.  @Ramhound I didn't see a way to extend the rollback window -- Do you have any more info on that?

Comment: @DaveTheMinion I *seem* to trigger the issue more frequently when I RDP into my Windows 11 system.  Are you using RDP by any chance?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - Run `DISM /Online /Set-OSUninstallWindow /Value:60` to extend it to 60 days, this has to be done before timeframe expires, otherwise the rollback can't be performed.  I can't speak to what happens if you attempt to rollback on the (10th) or (60th) day

Comment: @Ramhound Many thanks!  That gives me a little more room to test the other fixes.  (Feel free to mark this for deletion when read as it is a "thank you" only comment ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I don't use RDP very often, but I do use NoMachine quite heavily, and it feels like it happens more often when I'm using it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Any updates from your side?

Comment: @DaveTheMinion Uninstalled GeForce Experience for now.  Still hitting my "slowdown" at least once a day.  I'm now suspecting Vivaldi (but not 100% sure).  When I leave the PC and come back to it several hours later, Vivaldi seems to get be the main app that doesn't return to "normal" performance.  Logging out and back in (without a full reboot) seems to restore me to a good state, but if I don't do that, I'll end up with every application becoming unresponsive similar to what you describe.

Comment: Side note, I was researching the SMB issues that @Ramhound mentioned, and all I found so far was recurring posts about slowdown in SMB specifically.  However, I'm trying to track if the issue occurs more frequently after a do any transfer over SMB.

Comment: I also just re-read @Ramhound's comment and experience on this, and I'm thinking that perhaps my situation is closer to that than to yours.  I'm running ~200 tabs at the moment (and go up to 300) in Vivaldi, so I updated *all* the nVidia drivers, including Experience.  If that turns out to be the magic bullet for me, I'll ask Ramhound to write it up as an answer.  Won't be the answer for you, unfortunately, if that's the case, but it may help others.  Still wondering if there's a "remote display" (whether NoMachine or RDP) component involved, perhaps in combination with the display drivers.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I am my answer would literally be "download the current version GeForce Experience", I am not sure, I want to submit that type of answer to this question given it's unlikely to solve the author's problem.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Good luck to you. It's been a couple days since it happened. Maybe this week's update solved it? Too early for me to say though.

Comment: @Ramhound No luck. I've reverted back to 21H2. ☹️

Comment: @DaveTheMinion It may have been a recent update that solved it for me.  Things didn't turn around immediately after I last posted on the 14th, but the last 4 days or so have been pretty solid.  Sorry you had to go backwards.  I'm still keeping a close eye on things in case I need to rollback before the window expires.

Comment: Jinxed it -- Just had the issue again.  I was in Directory Opus working with a SMB share, so chalk a point up for that theory.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am not so sure that the SMB theory makes sense in my case because in most cases when it happened, I was not actively doing anything with my network drive connections. I mean, I suppose they were still technically active since I still had them mapped to drive letters, but it's not like I was seriously using them.

Comment: @DaveTheMinion My process right now is that when things start getting "wonky", I unmap my drive, then map it again.  The last time I did that, things completely recovered without a restart.  Also a side note that logging out of my account and back in also has the same "recovery" as a full reboot.  That's not to say that I think yours is/was SMB based - It's just my working theory at the moment for my problem.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds In my case, when things get "wonky", there's no way for me to unmap the drives because the system just straight-up freezes to the point of being unusable.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm still trying to figure out this issue, as it has now started happening to me on 21H2 as well. Do you know how read crash dumps? I was thinking of trying to use the "crash on control scroll" feature to force a blue screen when this happens next time.